# How can I clone part of the texture?

Tags: texturing

I'm working on an axe. I've modelled the axe and am working on texturing it. I unwrapped the texture and inserted a picture into the UV image editor and made the mesh fit the picture. The only problem is there is a white gap in the texture, and I want to clone part of the texture to the white gap. I've seen this done on youtube with a texture painting tool or something like that, but when I try it, it doesn't seem to work.

Here is a screenshot of it

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r8ee.jpg -

Thanks to anyone that replies :D

Comment: For future reference- you can attach the picture when asking a question instead of using a link

Comment: k, but can u help me with my question?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to figure it out. I don't have much experience with uv unwrapping.

Answer (score 4):

To use the clone brush :

- Select the clone brush in the paint tools
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to set the origin of what to clone from (the 3D cursor is set at this origin)
- Then simply paint on the target position

Painting with a strength set to 1 is often better, but it depends on what you want.

[image]

If you want to clone from a picture that is not in the current model, you may need to set this picture on another mesh then join the two meshes, as this tool does not handle to clone parts that are outside of the painted mesh.

Comment: Slight gotcha that I couldn't find documented anywhere: this tool doesn't seem to work in the image editor, unlike the other texture editing tools.